# Cannot change CSV delimiter to tab

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I'm going to export all of my data in mySQL using PHPExcel with CSV Format. Here is my code:

```
function exportHartatoCSV() {
    $memberid = $this->input->post('memberid');
    $tahun = $this->input->post('tahunpajak');

    $this->db->where('taxYear', $tahun);
    $this->db->where('memberID', $memberid);
    $query = $this->db->get('list_harta');

    $this->load->library("excel");

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A1', 'Tahun Pajak')
                ->setCellValue('B1', 'Pembetulan')
                ->setCellValue('C1', 'Kode Harta')
                ->setCellValue('D1', 'Jenis Harta')
                ->setCellValue('E1', 'Tahun Perolehan')
                ->setCellValue('F1', 'Harga Perolehan')
                ->setCellValue('G1', 'Keterangan');

    $row = 2;

    $workbookName = $this->MemberModel->getNPWP($memberid);

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$workbookName.'.csv"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');

    $objWriter->setDelimiter("\t");
    $objWriter->setEnclosure('');

    $total = 0;

    foreach ($query->result() as $key) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $key->taxYear);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$row, $key->pembetulan);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$row, $key->hartaID);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$row, $key->hartaName);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$row, $key->hartaYear);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$row, $key->hartaPrice);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$row, $key->hartaDesc);
        $total += $key->hartaPrice;
        $row++;
    }

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$row, "Total Harta:");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$row, $total);

    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

I want to change the delimiter from `,` to tab (like writing data to the next column. But it doesn't work. The strings are stick to each other. The output is like this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhVc7.png)

But I want the output is like this:

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjF02.png)

**What I really want is a normal-looking excel table, but with .csv format.**

Comment: What happens if you use double quotes for the enclosure, like `setEnclosure("");`?

Comment: Are you using Excel ? I mean you should view the CSV with a notepad or another software to see if it works, if you're using excel you need to tell it which delimiter are you using!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need tab-delimited text (csv) file or you just want "normal"-looking excel table?

You must remember that there is a system list delimiter that is used in excel by default. In windows you can set that delimiter in your **Region and Language**, in Additional settings. It's called as List separator there. In some countries default value is ";", in others ",".

If you don't want to change your default delimiter you have an option to choose delimiter in Excel when you open file.

**Update**

You can use both options, but it looks like it's easier to set the delimiter in PHPExcel export settings to that delimiter that is set by default in your client's OS, than explain them to set custom delimiter in excel when opening file.

> $objWriter->setDelimiter(";");

or

> $objWriter->setDelimiter(",");

**Update 2**

If you have clients from different countries and/or they use different operating systems (mac/linux, windows), so they may have different system separators, then you'll need to save 2 versions of each file (with both , and ; delimiters). Or you'll need to explain them how to work with it.

I'm putting this system setting screenshots just for example:

[Mac OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6vmJ.png)

[Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YDz4.png)

Comment: I want a "normal"-looking excel table with CSV format. Generated automatically by PHPExcel

Comment: I understand your situation. Read updated answer please,

Answer (score 0):

As @teeyo mentioned, you might need to make sure you import it using the delimiter in Excel (or other spreadsheet editor). It might already be correct in the data generated by CI:

[image]

To verify the data is correct in the file itself, you can open it in eg. Notepad++ and use the Show All Characters feature:

[image]

Comment: This module will be used by my clients who are not an IT-specialist. So I have to generate the tab automatically, without configure the settings in spreadsheet editor (Excel)

Comment: @WilliamsPerdana see my edit. You can use that way to verify the tab exists in the file. But from personal experience, unless you save the file in native Excel format (not *.csv), you will have to teach the end-user to open it with the import configuration. I don't think Excel has a feature that automatically detects separators in CSV files.